# Using filenames to create variable - PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a folder where files get dropped (daily, weekly) and I need to add the year and week/day, which are in the file name in a consistent format, as variables to my data frame. The prefix can change (e.g., `sales_report`, `cash_flow`, etc.) but the last characters are always `YYYY_WW.csv`.

For instance, for a weekly file I could manually do it for each file as:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df = spark.read.load('my_folder/sales_report_2019_12.csv', format="csv").withColumn("sales_year", lit(2019)).withColumn("sales_week", lit(12))
```

I would like to do the equivalent of using a substring function counting from the right of the file name to parse the `12` and `2019`. Were I able to parse the file name for these variables I could then read in all of the files in the folder using a wildcard such as `df = spark.read.load('my_folder/sales_report_*.csv', format="csv")` which would greatly simplify my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily extract it from the filename using the `input_file_name()` column and some string functions like `regexp_extract` and `substring_index`:

```
df = spark.read.load('my_folder/*.csv', format="csv")

df = df.withColumn("year_week", regexp_extract(input_file_name(), "\d{4}_\d{1,2}"))\
       .withColumn("sales_year", substring_index(col("year_week"), "_", 1))\
       .withColumn("sales_week", substring_index(col("year_week"), "_", -1))\
       .drop("year_week")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the below :

```
import glob
listfiles = glob.glob('my_folder/sales_report_*.csv')
for files in listfiles:
    weekyear = c.split('_',2)[-1].split('_')
    week = weekyear[1]
    year = weekyear[0]
    df = spark.read.load('files', format="csv").withColumn("sales_year", lit(year)).withColumn("sales_week", lit(week))
```