# PySpark read all json files in subfolders / directories (using a wildcard) and add the file/folder name

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am reading JSON data in to a spark dataframe using a wildcard. Is there any way to instruct the read operation to add the filename as an attribute to every json object?

```
wildcardFolderPath = folderPath + '/*/*.json' 
dataDf = spark.read.json(wildcardFolderPath)
```

This implementation has greatly improved performance of a previous version that read each file and appended it in to a "master" dataframe. However, in this file by file approach, each dataframe row is prefixed with a column containing the file name. This is used in onward processing to identify newer entries of duplicate keys.

For example, in:

```
 [{ filename: 20200403 | key: key1 | value: value1 }]
 [{ filename: 20200405 | key: key1 | value: changed once }]
 [{ filename: 20200511 | key: key1 | value: changed twice }]
 [{ filename: 20200801 | key: key1 | value: final value }]
```

We use the filename to order the values of key 1 and use a `PARTITION BY` to select the most recent. However, with the wildcard I cant find a solution to add the filename (or even the folder name which would work too). Is there one?

Comment: You can use the function `input_file_name()`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116904/1386551).

Comment: The files I have do not contain the filename. I want to add it.

Comment: You can access the filename using that function and extract the date part if needed. You have a complete example in the linked answer.

Comment: withcolumn input_file_name() looks like an option